# Does active directory log authentication success/failure with the OS?

Tags: active-directory, windows-authentication

For example, if I use an AD account to login on Windows 7 and then Windows 8, will I be able to tell in logs setup by default?
If not by default, how would I set this logging up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not explicitly, but it will show you the name of the computer. From there, you can cross-reference this with the AD object for the computer, which has the Windows version in it.

Comment: Is there a way to see this information historically? For example, can I see the ad objects state at some time in the past?

Comment: Alternatively, what defines a new ad object? If a machine changed OSes, could I then simply look at the last time the old OS's ad object was changed to see when the last login on a given OS was?

Comment: There is no historical view. If you reinstall an OS and rejoin it to the domain with the same name, them it will silently delete the old object and create a new one with the same name. What problem are you trying to solve? Maybe if you describe that, you'll get more usable information.

Comment: I'm trying to see the datetime that a machine changed OSes. The machine is a single user machine.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you might be able to find the date as to when a machine changed the Os by doing some advanced sleuth work in the registry of the computer, or in the event viewer if the change was recent enough. Active Directory logs do not store such information (i.e. when a computer's OS changed.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the date it changed OSes you could always run the systeminfo command on the workstation via script and send the result to a file etc:

```
systeminfo | find "Original Install Date"
```